# Why does resolveBinding() return null even though I setResolveBindings(true) on my ASTParser?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am writing an Eclipse plug-in that uses JDT AST's `ASTParser` to parse a method.  I am looking within that method for the creation of a particular type of object.

When I find a `ClassInstanceCreation`, I call `getType()` on it to see what type is being instantiated.  I want to be sure that the fully-resolved type being dealt with there is the one I think it is, so I tell the resultant `Type` object to `resolveBinding()`.  I get `null` back even though there are no compilation errors and even though I called `setResolveBindings(true)` on my `ASTParser`.  I gave my `ASTParser` (via `setSource()`) the `ICompilationUnit` that contains my method, so the parser has access to the entire workspace context.

```
final IMethod method = ...;
final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setSource(method.getCompilationUnit());
parser.setSourceRange(method.getSourceRange().getOffset(), method.getSourceRange().getLength());
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_CLASS_BODY_DECLARATIONS);
final TypeDeclaration astRoot = (TypeDeclaration) parser.createAST(null);
final ClassInstanceCreation classInstanceCreation = walkAstAndFindMyExpression(astRoot);
final Type instantiatedType = classInstanceCreation.getType();
System.out.println("BINDING: " + instantiatedType.resolveBinding());
```

Why does `resolveBinding()` return `null`?  How can I get the binding information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tucked away at the bottom of the overview of `ASTParser.setKind()`, carefully hidden from people troubleshooting `resolveBinding()` and `setResolveBindings()`, is the statement

> Binding information is only computed when `kind` is `K_COMPILATION_UNIT`.

*(from [the online Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html))*

I don't understand offhand why this would be the case, but it does seem to point pretty clearly at what needs to be different!

Comment: I have a similar case where the kind is K_COMPILATION_UNIT but still resolveBinding() returns null. Any idea why?

Comment: Just a late comment on *"why this would be the case"*: if you parse anything smaller than a compilation unit then you have no import statements, and hence binding resolution is likely to fail.