# Get the type of a FieldDeclaration in AST

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am working with a Java AST. How can I get the Type (e.g. String or MyOwnType) of a FieldDeclaration or VariableDeclaration? In ASTView I can see it under SimpleName > type binding, but with getters I cannot reach the member.
I tried the solution from [FieldDeclaration to IField - Getting IBinding from FieldDeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131793/fielddeclaration-to-ifield-getting-ibinding-from-fielddeclaration) but resolveBinding returns null when visiting the FieldDeclaration.

[Why does resolveBinding() return null even though I setResolveBindings(true) on my ASTParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631981/why-does-resolvebinding-return-null-even-though-i-setresolvebindingstrue-on?lq=1) not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, this was tough.
The last line made it possible to resolve the bindings and retrieve the type via `varDeclFrag.resolveBinding().getType().getQualifiedName();` although I already thought I did the same in setEnvironment when referring to `sources`:

```
String[] sources = { "C:\\a\\TheMightyExampleProject\\src" };
String[] classPaths = { "C:\\a\\antlr-4.1-complete.jar" };

parser.setEnvironment(classPaths, sources, new String[] { "UTF-8" }, true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
parser.setUnitName("C:\\a\\TheMightyExampleProject\\src"); // ftw
```

You can also check out the answer of Ida [bindings not resolving with AST processing in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017945/bindings-not-resolving-with-ast-processing-in-eclipse)

Comment: Sorry to disturb the slumber of this old question, but is there a way to get those string arrays "sources" and "classPaths" without hardcoding them? I'm trying to build a parser outside of a plugin too, and I can't get the types of fields either.

Comment: How is this theoretically supposed to work? _You_ need to tell your program, not the other way around. Or maybe I got you wrong

Comment: Out of all the examples on SO, this one works. The magic bit is setting the sources in the parser environment.